# Flutter error: The argument type 'List<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: list, flutter, dart, dynamic, arguments

I have been trying to past a `List<dynamic>` to a class that receives a `List<dynamic>` as an argument, but I am getting the following error:

```
The argument type 'List<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'.
```

Here's the code of both classes:

```
Widget _lista() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: menuProvider.cargarData(),
      initialData: [],
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
        return ListView(
          children: _listaItems(snapshot.data),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I am getting the error in the `snapshot.data` piece of code:

```
_listaItems(snapshot.data)
```

And here's the class receiving the data:

```
List<Widget> _listaItems(List<dynamic> data) {
    final List<Widget> opciones = [];
    data.forEach((opt) {
      final widgetTemp = ListTile(
        title: Text(opt['texto']),
        leading: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.blue),
        trailing: Icon(
          Icons.keyboard_arrow_right,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        onTap: () {},
      );
      opciones..add(widgetTemp)..add(Divider());
    });
    return opciones;
  }
```

I have not found any information on how to work this out and I don't understand the root of this error since both data types are equal. Any recommendation to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
`_listaItems(snapshot.data!)`

Comment: My kind sir... thank you so much... that fixed it, but can you shed some light on the "!" at the end?

Comment: The `!` removes the nullabiliy ( `?` ) of the variable. Either that or you could add a `?` at your `_listaItems` parameter `data`

Comment: I see now... understood, thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud do like this, not use directly ! operator.

```
Widget _lista() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: menuProvider.cargarData(),
      initialData: [],
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data != null 
                        ? _listaItems(snapshot.data) 
                        : CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I assume this is a binary (if else) operation here, but what does CircularProgressIndicator() method do? (Sorry for the question, I am learning Flutter)

Comment: It shows Loading Indicator, I thought you'll find it useful.

Comment: Definitely trying that out, thank you so much for your time.